# accessing nested properties based on structure

Tags: javascript

Could anyone please give me an alternate syntax to the following

```
  var id = '-JLxSeCPUCVN13FxifTY';
  var ResultsContainer = results[id];
  var i=0;
  for(var k in ResultsContainer)
  {
    var TheArrayOfObjectsThatIneed = ResultsContainer[Object.keys(ResultsContainer)[i]];
    console.log(TheArrayOfObjectsThatIneed); 
    //loop the TheArrayOfObjectsThatIneed do the processing 
    i++;
  }
```

as you see in the image i have an array within an object within an object and i have no idea what the property names are but the structure is always the same {results:{id:{idthatidontknow:[{}]}}} and all i need is to access the arrays[image]

the above code is working nicely but i am new to javescript and i was wondering if there is a nicer syntax and if i am doing it the right way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps something like this?

```
var id = '-JLxSeCPUCVN13FxifTY';
var ResultsContainer = results[id];
for(var k in ResultsContainer) {
    if (ResultsContainer.hasOwnProperty(k)) {
        var TheArrayOfObjectsThatIneed = ResultsContainer[k];
        console.log(TheArrayOfObjectsThatIneed); 
        //loop the TheArrayOfObjectsThatIneed do the processing 
    }
}
```

Comment: is there any performance difference, i avoided using has own property because there is one property only

Comment: Well for one thing, you aren't fetching the keys of the ResultsContainer every loop.